# NodeJS http.get() async and callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, http-get

I am working on the "learnyounode" practice 9, Juggling Async. The problem states:

> This problem is the same as the previous problem (HTTP COLLECT) in
>   that you need to use http.get(). However, this time you will be
>   provided with three URLs as the first three command-line arguments.
>       You must collect the complete content provided to you by each of the URLs and print it to the console (stdout). You don't need to print
>   out the length, just the data as a String; one line per URL. The catch
>   is that you must print them out in the same order as the URLs are
>   provided to you as command-line arguments.

I have two different solutions which are mostly the same. The only difference is that the working one is modularized while the other is not (and does not work). I am having trouble understanding the differences and why. Here are my code:

Working solution:

```
const http = require('http');
const bl = require('bl');

var msgs = [];
var complete = 0;

function printAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log(msgs[i]);
    }
}

function doGet(i) {
    http.get(process.argv[i + 2], function(res) {
        res.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            complete++;
            msgs[i] = data.toString();
            if (complete == 3) {
                printAll();
            }
        }));
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    doGet(i);
}
```

Wrong solution `singleFunction.js`:

```
const http = require('http');
const bl = require('bl');

var msgs = [];
var complete = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    http.get(process.argv[i + 2], function(res) {
        res.pipe(bl(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            }
            complete++;
            msgs[i] = data.toString();
            if (complete == 3) {
                for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    console.log(msgs[j]);
                }
            }
        }));
    });
}
```

Output of `learnyounode run singleFunction.js`:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I am not even sure what are the things I do not fully understand here. Is it NodeJS event loop, or passing Javascript functions, or NodeJS callbacks, or even something else? Thank you for the help.

EDIT:
Finally figured out the reason and fix with the helpful comments. The reason modularized solution works is because scope of `i` in `doGet(i)` as well as the callback are not the same as the for-loop. Therefore the index value is correct. The main for-loop would finish and increment `i` to 3 way before any callback is invoked, hence getting `undefined` at index 0,1,2.

Comment: You're declaring a local `i` inside the `bl()` callback function. That will hide the more global `i`. Even without that, you'd run into the common problem of trying to use a loop index variable in a callback constructed in the loop.

Comment: in the "wrong" solution, try to print the value of msgs[3] instead, it will store the value of your last executed callback. The reason is function scope visibility of the `i` in the outer loop

Comment: in the first "correct" solution you create a closure, hence value of `i` is preserved, again, because it has a function scope visibility.

Comment: @Yerken, printing msgs[3] gave me the same message three times, not "undefined" anymore.

Comment: @derrdji exactly, you need to understand how variable scopes work in javascript

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: in other words this is a dupe of "For Loop closure: A Simple Practical Example"